# How can I produce a JSON_OBJECT instead of JSON_ARRAY as result to my API queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

For some time I have Struggled with this problem
I have distilled a short sample to produce my results

When Spring-Boot produces api output and there is more than one record it is enclosed as a JSON_ARRAY starting with [ and ending with ] with comma-seperated JSON_OBJECTS inside

I Want the result to be surrounded by another JSON_OBJECT like 
{entity:[{.....},{.....}]}

e.g.

```
[
    {
        "locationId": "l1",
        "locationName": "New York"
    },
    {
        "locationId": "l3",
        "locationName": "London"
    }
]
```

must become

```
{
location:{
    [{
      "locationId": "l1",
      "locationName": "New York"
     },
     {
      "locationId": "l3",
      "locationName": "London"
     }]
}}
```

```java
public class Location {
   private String id;
   private String name;
}
// Getter & Setters etc ommited
```

Obvously I have googled for this and have tried many solution and could not find any

If I add "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest"
to my project spring will create some endpoints for my entities that actually produces the desired results, however I have some non-standars queries that is excluded and I need to do them myself

If you can teach me to overcome this difficulty I will apreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class as follows:

```
public class LocationWrapper {
    private List<Location> location;
}
```

and return an instance of `LocationWrapper` from the `@RestController` method.

Comment: Perfect, I suspected this but was very unsure - Also I din't know how to implement this but your answer motivated me to persit - Now its working
@Hasan Thank you very much!